# Are there theorems dealing with the "amount of oscillatory divergence" of series?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, dirichlet-series

Are there a set of theorems dealing with "amount of divergence" series?

Let me explain by example. The Dirchlet $\eta$ series $\sum_n (-1)^{n-1} n^{-x}$ converges when $x > 0$. We may say amount of divergences when $x>0$ is $0$. When $x=0$, the partial sum oscillates between $1$ and $0$, thus amount of divergence at $x=0$ is $1$ and more specifically the limit of oscillations is between $1$ and $0$. Are there theorems dealing with this kind of analysis?

I would like to examine if partial sum fluctuations stay within a certain range for various values of $x$ for a few series.

Thank you!

Comment: You might enjoy Hardy's book on divergent series https://sites.math.washington.edu/~morrow/335_17/Hardy-DivergentSeries%202.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The study of divergent series up to the early twentieth century was masterfully summarized in Hardy's book [1], see also [2]. Significant extensions were developed by Boshernitzan in the 1980's, see [3], [4], [5], with some overlapping work by Rosenlicht [6].

[1] Hardy, Godfrey Harold. Divergent series. Vol. 334. American Mathematical Soc., 2000.

[2] Tucciarone, J., 1973. The development of the theory of summable divergent series from 1880 to 1925. Archive for history of exact sciences, 10(1), pp.1-40.

[3] Boshernitzan, Michael. "An extension of Hardy’s class L of “orders of infinity”." Journal d’Analyse Mathématique 39, no. 1 (1981): 235-255.

[4] Boshernitzan, Michael. "Hardy fields and existence of transexponential functions." Aequationes mathematicae 30, no. 1 (1986): 258-280.

[5] Boshernitzan, M., 1984. Discrete" Orders of Infinity". American Journal of Mathematics, 106(5), pp.1147-1198.

[6] Rosenlicht, Maxwell. "Growth properties of functions in Hardy fields." Transactions of the American Mathematical Society 299, no. 1 (1987): 261-272.